# Detect whether path is absolute or relative

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, path

Using C++, I need to detect whether given path (file name) is absolute or relative. I can use Windows API, but don't want to use third-party libraries like Boost, since I need this solution in small Windows application without expernal dependencies.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Windows API has [`PathIsRelative`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is defined as:

```
BOOL PathIsRelative(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpszPath
);
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Although it would work in 99% of the times, it is not a perfect solution. Here're two major reasons why: 1. There should technically be three return options: `yes`, `no`, and `error determining`. 2. This limitation: `maximum length MAX_PATH`. Unfortunately I didn't find a Windows API that could do this reliably...

Comment: Use #include <shlwapi.h>

Answer (score 16):

Beginning with C++14/C++17 you can use [`is_absolute()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/is_absrel) and [`is_relative()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/is_absrel) from the [filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

```
#include <filesystem> // C++17 (or Microsoft-specific implementation in C++14)

std::string winPathString = "C:/tmp";
std::filesystem::path path(winPathString); // Construct the path from a string.
if (path.is_absolute()) {
    // Arriving here if winPathString = "C:/tmp".
}
if (path.is_relative()) {
    // Arriving here if winPathString = "".
    // Arriving here if winPathString = "tmp".
    // Arriving here in windows if winPathString = "/tmp". (see quote below)
}
```

> The path "/" is absolute on a POSIX OS, but is relative on
>   Windows.

In C++14 use [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> // C++14

std::experimental::filesystem::path path(winPathString); // Construct the path from a string.
```