# Types of absolute paths in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems, ntfs

Just curious what is the term (in Windows) for paths like this?

```
"\Users\Name\Desktop\1\dest dir1"
```

I know it's an absolute path that refers to the root of the drive.

And the second question, is there an API to differentiate it from a "true" absolute path? Path as such:

```
"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\1\dest dir1"
```

PS. I'm obviously asking in general and not just in relation to that sample path.

Comment: I would call the first one a relative path since it is relative to whatever the current drive is.  It's really no different than `..\foo` in that it depends on the working directory.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: `PathIsRelative` reports both paths as absolute.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I may be wrong, but wouldn't it be the same as .\foo, not ..\foo, because ..\foo looks in the directory below?

Comment: @deviantfan: So to tell one path from another is to check for a single slash in the front? What if it's a forward-slash? That is why I was looking for an API.

Comment: _'is there an API to differentiate it from a "true" absolute path?'_  Yes: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't use Boost. Can you be more specific about the exact method?

Comment: While it is true that `PathIsRelative` would return `FALSE` for both paths, that doesn't change the fact that the first is relative to the current working directory.  If you use `GetFullPathname` with the working directory set to different drives you'll see the full path follows the current drive letter.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: This is not correct. `"\Folder"` is relative to the current drive and not the current working directory. And according to the link above it is considered an absolute path. Which, if you start looking into it, is not exactly the same as when one uses a drive designator (i.e. `C:\\`)

Comment: The current working directory is on the current drive.  If you had two drives, C: and D:, and were to run [this](http://pastebin.com/NVrg7JnJ) you would see the full path follows the working directory for your first example.

Comment: @c00000fd Can you define what you mean by the current drive

Answer (score 0):

So judging from what I've seen so far, it should be this (with the absence of the WinAPI), right?

```
BOOL IsAbsoluteToDrivePath(LPCTSTR pszPath)
{
    //Checks if the path is absolute to drive
    //RETURN:
    //      = TRUE if yes, it is an absolute to the drive path
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    if(pszPath &&
        pszPath[0])
    {
        //Check first char to be a slash
        //INFO: Proved experimentally that / and \ may be treated equally...
        if(pszPath[0] == L'\\' ||
            pszPath[0] == L'/')
        {
            //Do we have a 2nd char?
            if(pszPath[1])
            {
                //Second char should not be a slash
                if(pszPath[1] != L'\\' &&
                    pszPath[1] != L'/')
                {
                    //Not a slash, then it's an absolute path
                    bRes = TRUE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //This is a root path (i.e. "\")
                bRes = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you're wrong, 
in windows the absolute path always start's with the drive's letter or server's name
while a relative path is a path that derivates from the current location you're working with and it begins with "\" or without it.

if you use your "absolute path" it will be looking for a "\Users\Name\Desktop\1\dest dir1" inside your working directory

also :
[Detect whether path is absolute or relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377642/detect-whether-path-is-absolute-or-relative)

PathIsRelative

Comment: Please read the link that @deviantfan provided above: _"A single backslash, for example, "\directory" or "\file.txt". This is also referred to as an absolute path."_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths

Comment: In doubt, just try a `dir \\` in the command line... It´s *not* the current working directory.